# Converting nested json to a csv, where each row includes innermost values and all parents values

Tags: python, json, csv

I am looking to create a python script to be able to convert a nested json file to a csv file, with each inner most child having its own row, that includes all of the parent fields in the row as well.

My nested json looks :

(Note this is just a small excerpt, there are hundreds of date/value pairs)

```
{

"test1": true,
"test2": [
    {
        "name_id": 12345,
        "tags": [
            {
                "prod_id": 54321,
                "history": [
                    {
                        "date": "Feb-2-2019",
                        "value": 6
                    },
                    {
                        "date": "Feb-3-2019",
                        "value": 5
                    },
                    {
                        "date": "Feb-4-2019",
                        "value": 4
                    }
```

The goal is to write to a csv where each row shows the values for the inner most field and all of its parents. (e.g, `date`, `value`, `prod_id`, `name_id`, `test1`). Basically creating a row for each date & value, with all of the parent field values included as well.

I started using this resource as a foundation, but still not exactly what I'm trying to accomplish:

[How to Flatten Deeply Nested JSON Objects in Non-Recursive Elegant Python](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-flatten-deeply-nested-json-objects-in-non-recursive-elegant-python-55f96533103d)

I've tried tweaking this script but have not been able to come up with a solution. This seems like a relatively easy task, so maybe there's something I'm missing.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of what you want to do is very data-format specific. Here's something using a function loosely derived from the "traditional recursive" solution shown in [linked resource](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-flatten-deeply-nested-json-objects-in-non-recursive-elegant-python-55f96533103d) you cited since it will work fine with this data since it's not that deeply nested and is simpler than the iterative approach also illustrtated.

The `flatten_json()` function returns a list, with each value corresponding to keys in the JSON object passed to it.

Note this is Python 3 code.

```
from collections import OrderedDict
import csv
import json

def flatten_json(nested_json):
    """ Flatten values of JSON object dictionary. """
    name, out = [], []

    def flatten(obj):
        if isinstance(obj, dict):
            for key, value in obj.items():
                name.append(key)
                flatten(value)
        elif isinstance(obj, list):
            for index, item in enumerate(obj):
                name.append(str(index))
                flatten(item)
        else:
            out.append(obj)

    flatten(nested_json)
    return out

def grouper(iterable, n):
    """ Collect data in iterable into fixed-length chunks or blocks. """
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return zip(*args)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    json_str = """
        {"test1": true,
         "test2": [
             {"name_id": 12345,
              "tags": [
                    {"prod_id": 54321,
                     "history": [
                        {"date": "Feb-2-2019", "item": 6},
                        {"date": "Feb-3-2019", "item": 5},
                        {"date": "Feb-4-2019", "item": 4}
                     ]
                    }
              ]
             }
         ]
        }
    """

    # Flatten the json object into a list of values.
    json_obj = json.loads(json_str, object_pairs_hook=OrderedDict)
    flattened = flatten_json(json_obj)
    print('flattened:', flattened)

    # Create row dictionaies for each (data, value) pair at the end of the list
    # flattened values with all of the preceeding fields repeated in each one.
    test1, name_id, prod_id = flattened[:3]
    rows = []
    for date, value in grouper(flattened[3:], 2):
        rows.append({'date': date, 'value': value,
                     'prod_id': prod_id, 'name_id': name_id, 'test1': prod_id})

    # Write rows to a csv file.
    filename = 'product_tests.csv'
    fieldnames = 'date', 'value', 'prod_id', 'name_id', 'test1'
    with open(filename, mode='w', newline='') as csvfile:
        writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames)
        writer.writeheader()  # Write csv file header row (optional).
        writer.writerows(rows)

    print('"{}" file written.'.format(filename))
```

Here's what it prints:

```
flattened: [True, 12345, 54321, 'Feb-2-2019', 6, 'Feb-3-2019', 5, 'Feb-4-2019', 4]
"product_tests.csv" file written.
```

And here's the contents of the `product_tests.csv` file produced:

```
date,value,prod_id,name_id,test1
Feb-2-2019,6,54321,12345,True
Feb-3-2019,5,54321,12345,True
Feb-4-2019,4,54321,12345,True
```